# Ruby Mechanize scraping ResponseCodeError

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I'm trying to scrape all results page of a website, it works but sometimes the script stops and display this error:

```
502 => Net::HTTPBadGateway for https://website.com/id/12/ -- unhandled response (Mechanize::ResponseCodeError)
```

I would like to continue the script even if it found an error.

My script:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'csv'

a = Mechanize.new
CSV.open('datas.csv', "wb") do |csv|
    page = a.get("https://website.com/?page=1-200") #498
    number = 0
    page.links_with(:class => "btn btn-default").each do |link|
        post_link = link.href
        inside_page = a.get("https://website.com#{post_link}")
        title = inside_page.at("h1.serviceTitle").text.strip
        author = inside_page.at(".name").text.strip
        number+=1
        csv << [title, author]
    end
end
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is easily solved by proper exception handling. you can [check this page for a better explanation](http://blog.honeybadger.io/a-beginner-s-guide-to-exceptions-in-ruby/)

as for your code, you can handle the exception like so

```
CSV.open('datas.csv', "wb") do |csv|
  begin
    a = Mechanize.new
    page = a.get("https://website.com/?page=1-200") #498
    number = 0
    page.links_with(:class => "btn btn-default").each do |link|
        post_link = link.href
        inside_page = a.get("https://website.com#{post_link}")
        title = inside_page.at("h1.serviceTitle").text.strip
        author = inside_page.at(".name").text.strip
        number+=1
        csv << [title, author]
    end
  rescue => e
    // do nothing and move on to the next line
  end
end
```